# How to compare float to integer

Tags: java

I want to perform a simple operation from values in a Hash as follows:

```
boolean f=Float.valueOf(entry.getValue().toString())>15;
```

However when I run this I get the error as follows:

```
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451)
    at java.lang.Float.valueOf(Float.java:416)
    at Algorithms.HRMDx.HRMDiag(HRMDx.java:76)
```

I think this has something to do with how I am comparing the float to the number but I can't figure out why. DO I need to convert the integer to a float as well- I thought the conversion would be implicit

Comment: You have missed out the exception name and message!!

Comment: If you had looked at the stack trace you posted, you would have seen that the error comes from a method called "parseFloat".

Comment: Thats literally all I get. There is no exception name

Comment: I guess the problem with the Float.valueOf not with the comparing logic

Comment: Exceptions and stack traces exist for a reason. Read the docs for the error you're getting

Comment: try to debug and share entry.getValue().toString()

Comment: *"That's literally all I get. There is no exception name"* - I find that a bit hard to believe.  However.  What you need to do is run the code in a debugger and find out what the exception message actually is.  It should even tell you the value that it was attempting to parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that this expression:

```
  Float.valueOf(entry.getValue().toString())
```

is throwing an exception.  You have not included the exception and its message in the stuff you have shown us, but it is *probably* a `NumberFormatException` caused by trying to parse something that is not a well-formed number.

You need to find out what is being returned by `entry.getValue().toString()` so that you can figure out why the parse is failing.

You may also need to add some code to recover from "bad input" in that field, or whatever it is ...

---

> I thought the conversion would be implicit

This is nothing to do with conversion of `int` to `float` (or vice versa).  If the  `valueOf` call actually returned, then your `15` would be converted to `15.0` and the `>` test would work.

Comment: Yes. A non- number crept in and I didnt notice. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The error has nothing to do with conversion between int and float, or with the comparison.

As your stack trace clearly states, it is an error while parsing a float value from a string.

As none of us have any clue to what "entry" might be, it is impossible to say why the parsing fails.

Comment: That is no answer

Comment: No? Why is this not an answer?

Comment: Your original non-answer was *"As none of us have any clue to what "entry" might be, it is impossible to say why the parsing fails."*

Comment: Before your edits it looked like anything but an answer

Comment: Sorry, I've prematurely pressed add and didn't get that your comment was relative to that short time before the edit :D Thanks!